# How to pass element to append image to in to the image.onload() function

Tags: javascript, onload, appendchild

I am writing a library that creates multiple elements inside a wrapper element, and stores all this and its functions inside a JavaScript object. I am trying to avoid IDs, as there might be multiple instances of this object on a page. I have a function to allow the user to change some of the elements, and I need help figuring out how to append an image.

Here is the function:

```
foo.prototype.rebrand = function(line1, line2, imgUrl){
    this.branding.childNodes[1].innerHTML = line1;
    this.branding.childNodes[2].innerHTML = line2;
    var brandImage = document.createElement('img');
    brandImage.onload = function(){
        this.branding.childNodes[0].appendChild(brandImage);
                    //this won't work
    }
    brandImage.src = imgUrl;
}
```

You would call `foo.rebrand('hello', 'world', 'example.png')`

Unfortunately, inside the `.onload` function, `this` will refer to the image element itself. So, how can I pass `this.branding.childNodes[0]` in to the image onload?

If I write the function like so:

```
            brandImage.onload = function(anything){
        this.branding.childNodes[0].appendChild(brandImage);
                    //this won't work
    }
```

then `anything` will just be a reference to the `onload` event.

**Edit to add jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/KtJd6/

Comment: Have you tried `var that = this;` and use `that` instead? So you have a local reference to the `this`?

Comment: yeah i have var `self = this;` in my object, but in the onload, `self` seems to refer to the `window` object.

Comment: Do you have a more full fiddle demo to work with?

Comment: Your `self` in the fiddle is out of scope; if I move one `}` so the prototype declaration is inside that scope, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/KtJd6/1/. I don't know if this is a great idea; I would suggest a local `var self = this;` in the prototype.

Comment: I updated my answer below based on the your jsFiddle.

Comment: you're absolutely right... not sure why I didn't realize that would be a "private" variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the way you are referencing specific elements to retrieve elements, not childNodes.  This will make it a lot more robust.  And, when you do that, you won't need the reference `this` in the `onload` handler either.

```
foo.prototype.rebrand = function(line1, line2, imgUrl){
    var brandImage = document.createElement('img');

    // find child divs
    var divs = this.branding.getElementsByTagName("div");
    divs[0].innerHTML = line1;
    divs[1].innerHTML = line2;

    brandImage.onload = function(){
        divs[0].appendChild(brandImage);
    };
    brandImage.src = imgUrl;
};
```

Note, that I'm getting elements with `getElementsByTagName()` and NOT referring to direct `childNode` indexes.  This makes it insensitive to where text nodes are and is a lot more robust way of referring to elements you want to target and modify.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kkXCg/

Comment: `textNode`'s are also throwing a slight wrench into it with the `childNode` references: http://jsfiddle.net/ebYgg/

Comment: @JaredFarrish - you'll have to be a lot more specific about what you want help with and what your HTML looks like.  Referencing node indexes like you are doing is usually a BAD way to find a specific element.  Use classnames or something much more foolproof than `childNodes[1]`.

Comment: I'm not the OP; you're talking about the same problem I'm bringing up. `:)` And I'm guessing as to the markup (see my comment below the question). If query selectors are supported and jQuery or Mootools is not used, I'd suggest something along those lines.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski  - Now that I see there was a jsFiddle posted, I've updated my answer to not only fix the image problem, but to also remove the `childNode[1]` references and replace them with something more robust.

Comment: Thank you, I knew that the `childNode` method was not the best way to go, but I wasn't 100% sure what to replace it with.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski - I fixed one more thing in your code.  You have to set the `.onload` handler BEFORE you set `.src` or you might miss the `onload` event in some browsers (e.g. IE) if the image is in the browser cache.